# Read picture box mouse coordinates on click

Tags: c#, mouse, coordinates, picturebox

I have a Picture Box with a picture loaded and I want to read the location (as in x,y inside the Picture Box) when I click the image; is this possible ? Even more, can i read these coordinates (Points) when i mouse over ?

I know i have to use the events given (Mouse Click and Mouse Over) but don't know how to read the coordinates where the mouse pointer happens to be.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Though other answers are correct let me add my point to it.
You've pointed that you need to hook up `MouseClick` or `MouseOver` events for this purpose. Actually that is no need to hook those events to get `Coordinates`, you can get the `Coordinates` in just `Click` event itself.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;
    Point coordinates = me.Location;
}
```

The above code works since Click event's `e` argument wraps `MouseEventArgs` you can just cast it and make use of it.

Comment: This is the answer if OP wants to (I guess obviously) get the click point coordinates relative to the picturebox.

Comment: This is correct as long as there are no transformations on the image as it is rendered in the `PictureBox`.  If the rendered version is stretched, scaled, or panned, then the `MouseEventArgs.Location` property will need identical transformations applied to get the click in image coordinates.

Comment: @kdbanman what does transformations has to do with getting the clicked location of picture box? Op needs mouse coordinates with respect to picture box not image inside it.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the X and Y coordinates as follows,

```
 this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);

  int xCoordinate = Cursor.Position.X;
  int yCoordinate = Cursor.Position.Y;
```

If you want to get the coordinate within the picture box, use the following code,

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int xCoordinate = e.X;
    int yCoordinate = e.Y;
}
```

Comment: you don't need all of that for mouseUp but you can use it in mouse_hover

Comment: This gives the coordinates relative to the FORM. Not to the PictureBox boundary...

Comment: Isn't this answer pretty much identical as @NoIdeaForName's answer?

Comment: @StigCoder04 Yes, they are identical except the timestamp they are posted on :)

Answer (score 5):

i'll just sum up the answers:

in `MouseClick`, `MouseUp` and a lot of other events you have the `MouseEventArgs` which contains `Location` of the mouse.

in `MouseHover` however you don't have `MouseEventArgs` and therefor, if you need the cursor's location, use Coder example:

```
  private void Form1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);

     int xCoordinate = Cursor.Position.X;
     int yCoordinate = Cursor.Position.Y;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What about hooking up the MouseUp event and then getting the location from the MouseEventArgs?

Like this:

```
private void pictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point mousePointerLocation = e.Location;
}
```

Comment: It works with just a change : Point MouseLoc = e.Location; Thanks!

Comment: Yes I figured out my mistake after writing it as well. Thanks for pointing out! Glad it helped! :)